# Insert values into table from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table `AttendanceLog`.

Columns are:

- `EmpCode`
- `Date`
- `time`
- `type`

This is for attendance punch details

```
empcode date           time      type
01      19.08.2016     080530    64
01      19.08.2016     092030    64
01      19.08.2016     084030    65
```

The types are `64` for `Intime`, `65` for `outtime`.

I have another table.

Columns are

- `Empcode`
- `Date`
- `Intime`
- `outtime`

Now I want to insert into this table from `attendancelog` table.
Depending on the type I have to insert `time` into particular `intime` and `outtime` column.

pls help for an employee to fill `firstIntime` and `lastouttime`

My procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Attendance]
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @Empcode varchar(50),
        @Date varchar(50),
        @time varchar(10),
        @type varchar(10)

  Declare attcursor Cursor
  for
  select AC.AttEmpCode,AttDate,AttTime,AttType
  from BGUsersAttendanceCode AC inner join BGAttendanceTempTable AT 
       on AC.AttEmpCode=AT.AttEmpCode 
       order by AttType,AttDate

       open attcursor

       fetch next from attcursor into
       @Empcode, @Date, @time, @type

       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
       begin

       insert into BGUsersAttendanceLog values(@Empcode,@Date,@time,@time)

       fetch next from attcursor into
       @Empcode, @Date, @time, @type

       end

          CLOSE attcursor
      DEALLOCATE attcursor

END
GO
```

Comment: I have created stored procedure

Comment: I have created stored procedure no use

Comment: If you want to be helped, you shouldn't simply state your problem and wait for someone to write code for you. You should show what you have tried, explain why and how your code fails, then you could ask a question with a reasonable possibility to get a real helpful answer.

Comment: if u know u can help

Comment: Hi iswarya - can you describe how far you've got with the code you've written, and what _specific_ problems you have run into?

Answer (score 0):

**My interpretation of your requirements**

- You want to consolidate the rows in your `attendance` table, such that you end up with a single row for every `(empcode, date)` combination.
- For every such row, you want the new `InTime` column to be populated with the earliest `InTime` value if more than one exists for that `(empcode, date)` combination.
- Likewise, you want the new `OutTime` column to be populated with the latest `OutTime` values if more than one exists for that `(empcode, date)` combination.

**A few additional notes**

- I notice that you use the `varchar` data type for all your columns. That's unfortunate. If possible, you really should use the appropriate types (`datetime`, `int`, etc.). But I'll ignore that here, and will assume that you are preserving the `varchar` values.
- In your description, you say you have a single `attendance` source table.  But your SP code suggests that your source data comes from a join between 2 tables.  Since you haven't described this in detail, I'll just stick with your description of a single source table.  You can adjust as necessary.

**Setup**

```
create table OldAttendanceLog (
  AttEmpCode varchar(50),
  AttDate varchar(50),
  AttTime varchar(10),
  AttType varchar(10)
)

insert into OldAttendanceLog 
(AttEmpCode, AttDate, AttTime, AttType) 
values
('01', '19.08.2016', '080530', '64'),
('01', '19.08.2016', '092030', '64'),
('01', '19.08.2016', '084030', '65'),

create table NewAttendanceLog (
  AttEmpCode varchar(50),
  AttDate varchar(50),
  InTime varchar(10),
  OutTime varchar(10)
)
```

**INSERT statement**

You don't need all that complicated cursor code.  The insert can be accomplished in a single statement using conditional aggregation:

```
insert into NewAttendanceLog (AttEmpCode, AttDate, InTime, OutTime)
select AttEmpCode, 
       AttDate,
       min(case when AttType = '64' then AttTime end),
       max(case when AttType = '65' then AttTime end)
  from OldAttendanceLog
 group by AttEmpCode, AttDate
```

Comment: I have completed task..Thanks a lot

Comment: one more complication in this..now in NewAttendanceLog have to add work hours column..have to calculate each time and put into Workhours column

Comment: can you help.pleasw